# Can't save my JSON into a python dictionary. Have the errors as a picture

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to use json/os packages to import a json file as a python dictionary. The program gets the right file path(I checked and it was correct) .I'm having trouble with saving the file into the dictionary.

```
import json
import os

#get file path
CWD = os.getcwd()

jsonFilePath = ('%s/%s' % (CWD,'countries.json'))
print(jsonFilePath)
configProperties ={}

with open(jsonFilePath,'r') as json_file:
    configProperties = json.load(json_file)
    print(configProperties)
```

[Errors I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j99lk.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import os

CWD = os.getcwd()

jsonFilePath = ('%s/%s' % (CWD,'countries.json'))
print(jsonFilePath)
configProperties ={}

with open(jsonFilePath,'r') as json_file:
    configProperties = json.load(json_file)
    print(configProperties)
```

Your code already works fine, The erros which you have shown here,may be the json decode error ,and please make sure that json file ,key-value pairs to be in double quotes,unless it is value of the key other than string datatypes

Comment: I replaced all the single quotation marks with double quotes but it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you please share your json file?so that i can help you.

Comment: I tried using another json file and that worked. Seems to be a problem with formatting with the JSON file I was using. Thank you!

Comment: Yes its worth . Please accepting or upvote the answer if it helped you